# Differences - As / The way / like

Tags: sentence-construction

> 1. It might not be possible to continue the relationship as it used to be.
> 2. It might not be possible to continue the relationship the way it used to be.
> 3. It might not be possible to continue the relationship like it used to be.

I'm not sure whether each sentence means the same thing as the other does. I would really appreciate it if you could help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All are correct and have the same meaning. #1 is the most formal wording, #3 the most informal.

Comment: The use of "like" as an adverb, once considered wrong, has been gradually gaining acceptance in America over the past several decades. It has not quite yet achieved "formal" status; not in the way "as" has.

Comment: @Brian Hitchcock - Thanks. That is exactly why #3 is the most informal.